# Would like to only see one relationship Neo4j Admin Web Console with a Cypher Query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

My neo4j data base is growing in complexity and I would like to perform queries so that i can see my data set visualized by only one type of relationship

I am having trouble refining the output in the neo4j console so that I only see nodes bound by one relationship instead of "(completed with 3 additional relationships)".

I have tried this query amongst others without luck:

```
MATCH (a)-[rel:ALL_RESOURCES]-()
WHERE rel = 'ALL_RESOURCES'
RETURN a
```

I would be very grateful for any help someone can provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `WHERE` clause is not needed; by specifying the relationship type in the `MATCH` clause, you are already constraining your query to the `ALL_RESOURCES` relationship type. This is all you should need:

```
MATCH p = ()-[:ALL_RESOURCES]-()
RETURN p LIMIT 50;
```

Then, you'll want to move the "Autocomplete" slider in the Neo4j browser to OFF.

[image]

Comment: And you definitely want to limit your results, e.g. by using LIMIT 50 or 100

Comment: Yeah, definitely. Edited.